# Collections.frequency not working correctly in Android

Tags: java, android, hashset

I have a code in my android phone to find duplicate numbers via collections.frequency. This code works fine in a java program only on android. But not as an app on android. Here is what I have as a code in android.

```
ArrayList<String> ll = new ArrayList<String>();
String item = inputText.getText().toString();
ll.add(item);
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(ll);
for (String temp : set)
{
    answertext.setText(temp + "shows that many times: " + Collections.frequency(ll, temp));
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
33 44 33 44 shows that many times: 1
```

It does not find any duplicates if the numbers are input by user via textbox.
However, if a take the userinput away in the code and replace it with this input:

```
ll.add("33");
ll.add("44");
ll.add("33");
ll.add("44");
ll.add("24");
ll.add("24");
```

the output will be like so:

```
44 shows that many times: 2
```

So here with this input the collections.frequency is working to find a duplicate number. But why only one number? And why 44 and not 33? And why is it not outputting all duplicate numbers like it does as a java program only on the phone. Without Android involved?
I'd like to make it work with userinput from a textbox.
On the Java side where it works fine I got this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers you want to input: Input numbers separated by a space.");
int n = stdin.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    list.add(stdin.next());
}
System.out.println("\nCount all with frequency");
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
for (String temp : uniqueSet) 
{
    System.out.println(temp + " shows that many times : " + Collections.frequency(list, temp)); 
}
```

```
//Enter the amount of numbers you want to input
12 //hit the return key
22 33 44 22 33 44 22 33 44 22 33 44
//the output is like so:
Count all with frequency
33 shows that many times: 4
44 shows that many times: 4
22 shows that many times: 4
```

Why is this code working in Java but not on android?

Comment: In your Android code, your list has only one item in it. How could it have duplicate items if it only has one item?

Comment: O.K. If it has only one Item, how can a user add more Items? And why if this input is used: ll.add("33");
ll.add("44");
ll.add("33");
ll.add("44");
ll.add("24");
ll.add("24");
the output will be like so:
44 shows that many times: 2. Why does it pick the number 44 to show as a duplicate? Why not all numbers? There is more Items in the array, right?How can I make it work with userinput?

Comment: Hi immibis, you're a genius. I added a second textbox as an input box to the button. And input in one box the number 44 and in the second box 44 as well. Now when clicking the button it puts this out: 44 shows that many times: 2. Seems like you fixed my problem. According to this all I would need to do is add more textboxes to the code. But what if I wanted to add 50 numbers or so? That would require a whole lot of textboxes on the screen. Do you know of any other way to have only one box to input that many numbers? Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Immibis, Thank you so much for your help. That code snippet did the trick. Now if I add the numbers with a space inbetween it takes each one as a string and puts it into the ArrayList. And wth the .getText added at the very end it now outputs it like this: 44 shows that many times: 4. 22 shows that many times: 4. That's perfect. Didn't know about the .split part for input either. That really fixed it. Again, Thanks you very much. I'm really happy. Especially since the other guys put the last post on hold and then even closed it. But you didn't give up on me. I appreciate that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String item = inputText.getText().toString();
ll.add(item);
```

This adds one item to the list. I'm guessing you wanted to add each word separately, which you can do like this:

```
// split the input apart at the spaces
String[] items = inputText.getText().toString().split(" ");

// then add each part separately to the list
for(String item : items)
    ll.add(item);
```

Your second problem is that `setText`... sets the text. It doesn't add to the end of the text, it replaces what's already there. I don't know how you intended to display multiple strings, but you could do something like this:

```
// clear answertext
answertext.setText("");

for (String temp : set)
{
    // set the text to <whatever was already there> followed by this item
    answertext.setText(answertext.getText() + temp + "shows that many times: " + Collections.frequency(ll, temp) + "\n");
}
```